# How do you interpret "one near or in each end"?

Tags: meaning

I am reading European pressure vessel design standard and in a line it is written that

"2 large sightholes, one near or in each end or 1 handhole in the the central third of the cylindrical section."

it is for the option of using sightholes instead of handholes and according to it, I understand that I can use

- two sightholes one in the left end and one in the right end
- one in the end and one near the other end
- one in the end and one near the same end
- two near each end

How do you interpret this saying?

Comment: Roddy's answer has given you all the possibilities.  Of the 4 options your question postulates, the first 2 are OK; the third ("one in the end and one near the same end") is wrong because there would not be one near/in *each* end; the fourth is "two near each end" wrong because that would be a total of *four* sightholes!

Answer (score 4):

You have a cylinder. It has two ends. You need to put two sightholes in the cylinder, one at each end. *Each* sighthole must be *either* near the end, or in the end.

So if we label the ends of the cylinder A and B, the possible placements are:

- Hole in A and hole in B
- Hole in A and hole near B
- Hole near A and hole in B
- Hole near A and hole near B

The sentence is saying that *all* of  these are valid configurations.